# Looping a switch with for loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop, switch-statement

I can't get my for loop switch to work. I want the program to repeat the question if the user type a letter other than 'y','Y','n','N'. Can someone help me fix please?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  int flag = 0;
  char mstatus;

  printf("Are you married?\n");
  scanf(" %c", &mstatus);

  for (; flag == 1;) {
    printf("Are you married?\n");
    scanf(" %c", &mstatus);
    switch (mstatus) {
    case 'y':
    case 'Y':
      printf("You have answer yes for married");
      flag = 1;
      break;
    case 'n':
    case 'N':
      printf("You have answer no for married");
      flag = 1;
      break;
    default:
      printf("please re-enter a valid answer");
      scanf(" %c", &mstatus);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Loop doesn't start. Initialize flag to 1

Comment: A `while` loop or `do`...`while` loop would be clearer. Your condition is wrong. Use `for(; flag == 0; )` or better `while(flag == 0)` or `do { ... } while(flag == 0);`

Comment: Just change `flag == 1` to `flag != 1`.

Comment: Take a debugger and step through the code. You'll quickly find all your errors. Debugging is an important part of coding.

Comment: out of the wrong test, why the first couple printf/scanf before the loop ? that first scanf input is not used. Also why the scanf into the 'default' case of the switch ? the input char is not used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have several problems in your code

The first couple

> ```
> printf("Are you married?\n");
> scanf(" %c", &mstatus);
> ```

is done for nothing because you do not use the read answer, remove these lines

In

> ```
> for (; flag == 1;) {
> ```

you immediately exit the loop because you initialized *flag* to 0, and this is not consistent with how you change the value of *flag*, compare it with 0 rather than 1

In

> ```
> default:
>   printf("please re-enter a valid answer");
>   scanf(" %c", &mstatus);
> ```

the *scanf* must be removed because you do not use read answer

Out of that, because you want to do the loop at least one time to ask for the answer and manage it, it is very more readable to use a *do ...while*

Also add a final newline when you print something

Example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  int flag = 0;

  do {
    char mstatus;

    printf("Are you married?\n");
    scanf(" %c", &mstatus);

    switch (mstatus) {
    case 'y':
    case 'Y':
      printf("You have answer yes for married\n");
      flag = 1;
      break;
    case 'n':
    case 'N':
      printf("You have answer no for married\n");
      flag = 1;
      break;
    default:
      printf("please re-enter a valid answer\n");
    }
  } while (flag == 0);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall d.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Are you married?
a
please re-enter a valid answer
Are you married?
y
You have answer yes for married
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Are you married?
d
please re-enter a valid answer
Are you married?
N
You have answer no for married
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Of course in your case there is nothing after the loop, so you can also simplify all removing *flag* and its management and replace the two first *break* by a *return 0*, of course in that case the loop can be *for(;;)* or *while(1)* etc

Probably *please enter a valid answer* is a better choice than *please re-enter a valid answer* because by definition the user never enter a valid answer so he cannot re-enter one

Comment: Thank you!! Now I know how to use do while loop with switch!